# django redirect to other page and auto login to that page

Tags: django

Is there a way to redirect to other page and automatically log into that page?

So it's like I make django webpage with login and create link to facebook. When user clicks to facebook link, it should automatically login to his facebook page. Of course, I will have his facebook username and password on db I used to create the website.

Is this possible? Basically, I am trying to create interface page on django with link to several different webpage and make user access to his page by simply logon to this interface page alone.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you have a look at the Django-allauth, which is an Integrated set of Django applications addressing authentication, registration, account management as well as 3rd party (social) account authentication
It does most of the things you want, you can go through the documentation

https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html